# Can I include the same file multiple times in Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

I'm new to Asterisk, and I, would like to include a file that stores all of the common settings for my SIP phones to avoid duplication. Can I use `#include` more than once in sip.conf to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you actually tried to do it and see what happens?

(The answer is yes).

Comment: I figured it was so. I just don't have more than one phone yet :)

Comment: OK, but Asterisk doesn't know that, does it? :) Also, you can use this to include other options as well, just for testing.